# What is happening when a motor is set to a "high" speed?

Tags: current, motor, speed

When looking at different electrical devices like a blender, vacuum cleaner, fan, or drill, it's common for these devices to have different speed settings like "low" or "high" or some spectrum covering the two.

I'm assuming there's a motor that's drawing more current when set to high. How is this happening? Are there more circuits that are powered on (closed), which draws more current, which then increases the strength of the magnetic field powering the motor?

Comment: In a drill you're usually engaging an epicyclic gear to increase the torque in "low".

Answer (score 1):

The details depend very much on the type of motor being used here.  But a very common motor type for consumer products is the "shaded pole induction motor".  These are found in fans, some tools, toys, etc.

These are often fitted with a speed control which usually consists of:

1. A dropping resistor to control the voltage being supplied to the motor.
2. A tap on the motor's field winding.
3. Some combination of the above.

One problem with these types of motors is that the amount of speed control you can achieve is somewhat limited.

Other types of motors use different types of speed controls.  For example with DC motors the usual method these days is via PWM (pulse width modulation) of the supply voltage.

Answer (score 0):

With a blender for food mixer, the motor is likely a universal motor. That in a motor with a commutator like a DC motor. The field winding is connected in series with the armature. The speed is increased by connecting fewer turns of the field winding. That changes  the torque vs. speed capability curve to provide a higher no-load speed and a higher stall torque. The the actual operating speed, torque and current depend on the applied load. The motor operates at the intersection of its speed-torque capability curve and the load's speed vs. torque demand curve.

An electric drill is more likely to have an electronic voltage reduction circuit, but the result is similar.